# Wrong option value selected in meteor javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, meteor, drop-down-menu

I am building an app in Meteor and I am having trouble returning the value of a dropdown list. I have a page that has more than 2 rows where each row has a dropdown list. If I pick a value from the dropdown list in the SECOND row, my app returns the value from the FIRST dropdown list. The same issue occurs if I pick a value from any dropdown list other than the first row. It will return the value from the dropdown list in the first row. Here is my template:

```
<td>
<select id="clientsSelect" name="clients">
    <option disabled selected> Select Client </option>
    {{#each users}}
        <option value="{{this._id}}">{{this.profile.companyName}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
</td>
```

Here is my templates.js

```
Template.adminTemplates.events({
    "change #clientsSelect": function(event, template){
        var selectValue = template.$("#clientsSelect").val(); //grab value of dropdown list
        console.log(select val: ' + selectValue); //always returns value of the FIRST dropdown list
    }
});
```

Comment: `#clientsSelect` seems to be an `id` selector, and there should be no duplicate `id` in one page.

Comment: gotcha.. i've been trying to wrap my head around how I can generate a unique id for each of the select elements and and still be able to detect a change event for each select element on the client side... any ideas??

Comment: How about use class instead of id? Or you have to find how its template engine works so you can give unique id for each.

Comment: you're going about it the wrong way - you don't need unique names, you need to use `event.target` to get the element the click started from :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the value with `event.target.val()` so the value comes from the same element that was clicked. There's more [info in the docs.](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/forms-and-events)